# Login button only working after clicking several times

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, login, magento-community, phtml

I downloaded an extension for my store, in order to force the customers to login before using the website. The extension is named 'Ask to login' (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ask-to-login.html). It seems to be working fine, but **the login button only will perform the action after clicking several times** (like 4 or 5 at least). After doing so, it works fine.

My store uses Magento 1.7, and I have it installed on localhost over WAMP server.

Any ideas on why this is happening? The piece of code where the button is defined is:

```
<div id="login-form-div">
    <form id="asktologin-login-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getLoginPostActionUrl();?>">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
            <label for="email" class="required"><!-- <em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>--></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="asktologin_username" placeholder = "<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" style="color:#1a0000" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text" title="<?php echo $this->__("Email Address") ?>" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="pass" class="required"><!-- <em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?> --></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" name="asktologin_password" placeholder = "<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" style="color:#1a0000" class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a></li>
        <li>
            <button id="login-button" type="button"><?php echo $this->__('Login'); ?></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any comment will be much appreciated :-)

EDIT: I found out that it's not after clicking several times that it works, but some seconds after the first click. Still I don't know why this happens; I mean Magento is slow, at least on my store, but there's no apparent reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

the extension probably using a javascript file that's taking sometime to load.
check if there is any external javascript file requests  as well that causing the delay

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the extension source code, the event is defined after the DOM is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        winAsktologin = new Window({className:'dialog',title:"Ask to login",resizable:false,draggable:false,closable:<?php echo $this->newCustomer()?>,closeOnEsc:<?php echo $this->newCustomer()?>,width:450,height:220,minimizable:false,maximizable:false,showEffectOptions:{duration:0.5},hideEffectOptions:{duration:0.5}});
        winAsktologin.setZIndex(100);
        winAsktologin.showCenter(true);
        winAsktologin.setContent("login-to-buy", false, false);

        Event.observe('login-button', 'click', function(event){
            $('asktologin-login-form').request({
                onSuccess: function(r){
                    var result = r.responseText.evalJSON();
                    if(result.success) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                    } else {
                        $('loginerror').show().update(result.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

// ]]>
</script>
```

I assume that loading of the page takes the considerable time. Try to accelerate loading time of the page or don't display the button before your page is not fully loaded.